# Importing multiple csv files at the same time want the date data converted into (date and time) format in R

Tags: r, datetime, import

I have 20 files as .csv; all have the same headers as in the picture.

[image: This is how my data looks like]

I want to import them once at the same time. I want the timestamp converted from character format to date and time format.

I used this code for importing all the 20 files, which works fine.

```
path <- "~/Google Drive/Plumeflowlabs test/Data from Plume 17 Nov 2020/"

files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")

for(file in files)
{
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
  assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)),
    read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))

}
```

However, it doesn't contain the function to convert the date.

After that, I want to merge all the 20 files into one data frame by the timestamp.

I need help with that too.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a list of data frames instead of `assign`. This will make working with them much easier, including column conversion and merging them. [See my answer here for discussion and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207).

Comment: I don't know how to do it in base R... Can the solution include the packages [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and [`readr`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/) (both are a part of [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/))?

Comment: Thanks, Gregor.   I am always bad at creating the loop function. I will try to play with the codes, your answers there has a reach of information that looks very helpful. Today I spend time doing it manually importing the files one by one and changing the date format. It took time, but I had to do today the correlation analysis to see the agreement between at least three of my air pollution devices ( three files out of 20 ) how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. As no data was shared I can not test it. Taking into account the sage advice from **@GregorThomas** it is better to store data in a list like this:

```
#Code
path <- "~/Google Drive/Plumeflowlabs test/Data from Plume 17 Nov 2020/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
#Function to load and transform date
myfun <- function(x)
{
  df <- read.csv(x,sep="")
  df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',tz = 'GMT')
  return(df)
}
#Apply
List <- lapply(files,myfun)
#Names
names(List) <- files
```

The names are assigned in reference to `files` object. After that you can process them.

Comment: Thanks Duck.  It shows me an error.   Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: @user1894845 Try placing this code in the first line of the function `df <- read.csv(x,sep="",row.names=NULL)`. As no data was shared, I could not see the files! Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks, Duck. It worked well. What I understand is that there will be no data frames. All 20 files have been added as one large list.   For me, it's new to do such a process. If I want to merge the files by Timestamp it is a bit confusing. The idea of merging the files is to do a correlation analysis to test if the 20 devices give a good high agreement or not.   the correlation will be categorized for each column (PM2.5), (PM10), (NO2). I used to do this with only two and three devices, which is so easy.

Comment: @user1894845 After that you can assign names and then use `list2env(YourList,envir = .GlobalEnv)` and you will get the individual dataframes!

Comment: @user1894845 This can give you a hint for merging dataframes in a list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list